# Autodesk.DataVisualisation example doesn't seem to working

Tags: visualization, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've followed the example on the Data Visualisation documentation to create sprites but while I don't get any error, the sprites are not loading in the scene or are not visible. This is the link to the doc: https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/

Any idea why?
I've tried to isolate the sprite dbid and still can't see anything.

Comment: any error or warning in console?

Comment: I don’t see any errors in the console but still can’t see the sprites. I’ve tried to focus on them using their dbid and it’s all empty

Comment: it's hard to know without looking at the code, can you please try animating sptrites using this code? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77411638/problem-of-aps-iot-extensions-demo-and-animating-sprite-viewablessprite-cant-b/77479125#77479125
i think viewable data could be missing, please try to debug with breakpoints and check if any reference is undefined or null

Comment: I would like to take a look at it over a Zoom call, please book your session here https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services/varunpatil , in case the time zone doesn't suit you, you can try Eason for Taiwan timing, Petr for Europe or Michael for US time zone https://calendly.com/autodesk-platform-services

Comment: it's working now! I added the animation code and sprites display correctly - thanks!

Comment: how do you place the sprite sensors in relation to a model? there isn't a built-in function pass globalOffset