Autodesk Forge: set DataVisualisation sprite offset or other THREE js sprite parameters
Following this guide https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/dataviz/v1/developers_guide/examples/sprites/ i added a system in my forge viewer app to add sprite on mouse click
My question is, appart from changing spriteSize aren't there other parameters that could be changed, say for example the sprite anchor point, like Threejs sprite https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Sprite.center
Thank you in advanced

you can change the position using this code https://stackoverflow.com/a/77479125/5747150 and scale with https://stackoverflow.com/a/78601212/5747150. Under the hood, sprites are created using THREE.BufferGeometry() and not THREE.Sprite. So getting an anchor point is not available.
